# clear the previously drawn chart MPAndroidChart - Android?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using from [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). How can I clear the previously drawn chart ?

I am using from (Line Chart (Dual YAxis))

Comment: just clear the arrayList you have passed to it. And try to redraw the chart again with empty array.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 23):

You have to add the following line for the clear previous chart.

```
arraylist.clear();
mChart.invalidate();
mChart.clear();
```

Comment: Perfect! Also note for other people: I had also had an issue because I was not clearing my ArrayList so it was storing all the previous items. xD

Comment: Perfect! its working! we should have to reset arrayList or collection object

Answer (score 13):

```
private fun resetChart() {
    barChart.fitScreen()
    barChart.data?.clearValues()
    barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = null
    barChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
    barChart.clear()
    barChart.invalidate()
}
```

This is Kotlin but I found I needed to do all the steps to avoid crashing things.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to call

`mChart.clear();`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the LineChart as a Fragment inside a ViewPager.  All I had to do to clear the old data was assign the associated LineDataSet object to null.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may not have reference to ArrayList, so you have to do something like that to to that properly.

```
if(chart.getData() != null)
    chart.getData().clearValues();

chart.clear();
```

**Note : chart.clear() assign null to mData and call invalidate** on chart so you don't need multiple calls.

If you still have some zooming issues, you can use.

```
chart.setFitBars(true);
chart.fitScreen();
```

Source : https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.html#clear--

Answer (score 0):

If you have already a dataset, Just remove it, before going to add new data

```
if (mDataSet != null) {
    binding.chart.lineData.removeDataSet(mDataSet)
}
    
// create a dataset and give it a type
val set1 = LineDataSet(values, "Data1")
val dataSets: ArrayList<ILineDataSet> = ArrayList()
// add the data sets
dataSets.add(set1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need to clear chart. you need to clear the LIST you pass in, while setting up chart, it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the chart value by adding these lines

```
chart.data = null
chart.invalidate()
```